# Any tool/IDE/script to limit my C code to a maximum of 80 characters per line?

Tags: c, linux, coding-style, ide

I have so much C code. I need to edit that code to follow some coding line tips. So I need to limit all my C code to a maximum of 80 characters per line. Instead of editing each line of code, how can I perform this transformation with a tool/IDE/script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One such tool I know of is [indent](http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/) on Linux. It can be used to format your code in any style. Example from the man page:

> The  Linux style is used in the linux kernel code and drivers:
>
> indent test/metabolism.c -linux

Another switch, more specific to your questions:

> -ln, --line-lengthn
>
> Set maximum line length for non-comment lines to n.